# Display value in View layer (Cakephp)

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.0

How can I display Organisation value in view, I tried this , but it does not work 
Code in Model :

```
 function getOrganisationName($organisation_id){
    return $orgaName = $this->find('list',array('conditions' => array('Organisation.id' => $organisation_id), //array of conditions

                           'fields' => array('Organisation.name')));


    }
```

Code in Controller  :

```
$orgName = $this->Organisation->getOrganisationName($organisation_id);
$this->set(compact('indicators', 'organisations', 'rejections', 'projects', 'organisation_id','orgName'));
```

code in view :

```
   echo  $orgName['organisation']['name'];
```

Comment: Either you don't know how to access the correct value in $orgName or your function doesn't work. To check $orgName, just var_dump it. As far as your function, why not use Cakephp's `field` function?

Comment: In view , use `print_r($orgName);` . And then arrange your code accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Code in your view should be

```
echo  $orgName['Organisation']['name'];
```

Also you can use cakephp [findById($id)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby) or [find(‘first’)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first) to retrieve your data.